# curl to wget conversion

Tags: curl, wget

how to convert this curl code to wget code?

```
curl -I -s localhost | grep -o 'sid=.*'

curl 'localhost' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36 OPR/68.0.3618.125' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' \
  --data-binary '{"loginProfile":4,"username":"1","password":"123","save":true,"accountType":"csc","accessType":"csc-community"}' \
```